# Rotating Recorded Mouse Movements [Java]

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouse, mouselistener

I created a fun small project with the goal of recording natural mouse movements that I make and then play it back but orient it towards a target.

**Question**: So let's say I make and record a natural movement that ends at x: 250, y: 278, now what I want is to make the natural movement recording end at the target coordinates that I specify (EX: x: 100, y: 100).

Now for the code: (Please note that the code isn't clean what so ever but It's just the first prototype if I may say so, so please have this in mind while reading it).

**How I record movements**:

1. When a MOUSE_MOVED event occurs, recording starts and ends at MOUSE_PRESSED.

(Main.recordMoves has to be set to true for the above to happen, I set it to true/false using Scanner System input.)

2. The mouseMoved method invokes the MovesRecorder.record(MouseEvent e) method whenever a MOUSE_MOVED event occurs.
3. The mousePressed method sets the Main.recordMoves boolean to false and adds the recording to a Records list.

**Mouse**.java:

```
public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private Point location = new Point(0,0);
        
    private boolean mouseOnScreen = false;

    private Component c;

    public Mouse(Component c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void pushStraight(int x, int y) {
        if(!mouseOnScreen) {
            c.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c,MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, System.currentTimeMillis(),0,x,y,
                    0,false));
            mouseOnScreen = true;
        }
        c.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c,MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,System.currentTimeMillis(),0,x,y,
                0,false));
        location.setLocation(x,y);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if(Main.recordMoves) {
            Main.recordMoves = false;
            MovesRecorder.currentMove.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - MovesRecorder.startTime;
            MousePatterns.moves.add(MovesRecorder.currentMove);
            MovesRecorder.currentMove = null;
        }
        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseOnScreen = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseOnScreen = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        location.setLocation(e.getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        location.setLocation(e.getPoint());
        if(Main.recordMoves) MovesRecorder.record(e);
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public boolean isMouseOnScreen() {
        return mouseOnScreen;
    }

    public Component getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

**MouseRecorder**.java:

```
public class MovesRecorder {

    public static Move currentMove;

    public static Point lastPos; //First lastPos (startingPos) is set here by Main.java

    public static long startTime;

    public static void record(MouseEvent e) {
        if(currentMove == null) {
            currentMove = new Move(Screen.mouse);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        currentMove.movements.add(new Point(e.getPoint().x - lastPos.x,
                e.getPoint().y - lastPos.y));
        lastPos = e.getPoint();
    }
}
```

**Move**.java:

```
public class Move {

    public List<Point> movements = new ArrayList<>();

    public long time;

    private Mouse m;

    public Move(Mouse m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void executeEvents(int x, int y) { //This method as of now doesn't target the params.. it just does the recording
        for(Point p : movements) {
            execute(m.getLocation().x+p.x, m.getLocation().y+p.y, MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time / movements.size());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void execute(int x, int y, int event) {
        m.getC().dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(m.getC(),event,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),0,
                x,y,0,false));
    }

}
```

**Main**.java contains a loop and a switch statement of a Scanner to take commands:

```
while(true) {
    switch (s.next()) {
        case "movesRec":
            Main.recordMoves = true;
            MovesRecorder.lastPos = Screen.mouse.getLocation();
            break;
        case "move":
            MousePatterns.moves.get(0).executeEvents(100,100);
            break;
    }
}
```

**MousePatterns**.java contains a single static List for moves to be added in:

```
public static List<Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();
```

Help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

An example of a Recording: https://pastebin.pl/view/e461d2bd
I want it to start at X: 274 Y: 265 and end at X: 100, Y: 100

Comment: Do you want to use the data from the previous recorded movement to simulate a natural movement? For example: you want to use the data from the movement that ended on x: 250, y: 278 to simulate a movement that will end on x: 100, y: 100. Correct?

Comment: @GuilhermeSchaidhauerCastro Yes that is correct. Sorry for the late reply, was asleep.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following scenario where in a movement you recorded (x1, y1) is your starting point, (x2, y2) is your end point and the only point between these two points you recorded was the (xm1, ym1).

Of course in a real scenario you would have more points between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), but for simplicity let’s imagine there was just one.

x1: 0, y1: 0

xm1: 45: , ym1:60

x2: 100, y2: 100

And now you have a start point (x3, y3) and want to travel to (x4, y4) following the same movement you recorded before. To do that, you will need to find the (xm2, ym2).

x3: 15, y3: 45

xm2: ?, ym2: ?

x4: 150,  y4: 200

Considering that xp1 is how much percent of the distance between x1 and x2 that xm1 has travelled, you can do the following to find the xm2 and the ym2:

xp1 = xm1 * 100 / (x2 - x1)

xm2 = xp1 * (x4 - x3) / 100

yp1 = ym1 * 100 / (y2 - y1)

ym2 = yp1 * (y4 - y3) / 100

(in the (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) scenario the xp1 = 45% and yp1 = 60% because they have “travelled” 45% and 65% from the distance between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2))

solving the equation it becomes:

xp1 = 45 * 100 / 100 = 45

xm1 = 45 * 135 / 100 = **60.75**

yp1 = 60 * 100 / (100 - 0) = 60

ym2 = 60 * (200 - 45) / 100 = **93**

Now you only have to do this for every point you recorded from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) and you will have all the points to travel from (x3, y3) to (x4, y4)

Comment: Im sorry for the late reply, i will try this and let you know what happens. I appreciate the answer soo much thank you thank you

Comment: I've tested it but it only works for straight and parralel patterns.. but when its like loopy patterns, vertical patterns  it doesn't work

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a list of points you recorded in a movement as well as an starting and ending point you are using.

Comment: I apologize for not doing that, An example of a Recording: https://pastebin.pl/view/e461d2bd
I want it to start at X: 274 Y: 265 and end at X: 100, Y: 100